# Communication between two web pages using DELEGATES in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I m asked to communicate between two web pages in Asp.Net explicitly using delegates.

Comment: This makes no sense. What do you mean "communicate between pages"? Pages don't exist except while a client is requesting them.

Comment: You can communicate between user controls on the same page using delegates... But not between independent pages

Comment: @JohnSaunders the scenario is when a user click on a button on page#1 I want to display a message on page#2 webpage using delegates.
Message should be explicitly passed using delegates not using Session or QueryString. Thanks!

Comment: There is no page 2. Where did page 2 come from? Why are both pages open at the same time? Do you want clicking on page 1 to pop up page 2? Please think about what you want and ask clearly.

Comment: Ok Thank you boss for your responses.. I was asked this question in an interview yesterday.. I wanted to know how it will be done,,,,

Comment: Question does not make sense...however basically whenever you use an EVENT you are using an delegate...so on Click of a Button you either do CROSS POSTBACK or Server.Transfer to send data to second page.